# How can I get the value '77203' using the attribute code 'country_flag' using php

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

[image]

getAttribute('country_flag'); ?>
getData('value'); ?>
   
 getViewFileUrl('images/flags/usa.jpeg'); ?>" />

     getViewFileUrl('images/flags/vu.png'); ?>" />
 
     getViewFileUrl('images/flags/AU.png'); ?>" />

this is the code which I have written

Answer (score 0):

To fetch value of attribute Use:

First load/get your Product and then

```
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_text');

e.g: $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('country_flag');
```

Or

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
$ressource = $product->getResource();
$ressource->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'country_flag',$store->getId());
```

Hopefully, It will help you